# SQL Server LEFT OUTER JOIN HAVING criteria restricts results

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.WarehouseName, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SourceAreaReference AS CustomerID, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SourceAreaName AS CustomerName, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.Reference, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SecondReference, 
    dbo.StockItem.Code AS StockCode, 
    dbo.StockItem.Name AS [Artist/Title], 
    dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeName AS TransactionType, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN TransactionType.TransactionGroupID = 1 
           THEN transactionhistory.Quantity * - 1 
           ELSE transactionhistory.Quantity 
     END) AS Quantity, 
    MAX(CASE 
           WHEN dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeID = 15 
              THEN dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentDate 
           WHEN dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeID = 16 
              THEN dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentDate 
           ELSE dbo.TransactionHistory.TransactionDate 
        END) AS DefinitiveDate, 
    MAX(dbo.TransactionHistory.TransactionDate) AS StockTransactionDate,  
    dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentDate AS InvoiceDate
FROM
    dbo.TransactionHistory 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StockItem ON dbo.TransactionHistory.ItemID = dbo.StockItem.ItemID  
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TransactionType ON dbo.TransactionHistory.TransactionTypeID = dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit ON dbo.TransactionHistory.Reference = dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.SecondReference
GROUP BY 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SourceAreaReference, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SourceAreaName, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.Reference, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.SecondReference, 
    dbo.StockItem.Code, 
    dbo.TransactionHistory.WarehouseName, 
    dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeID, 
    dbo.TransactionType.TransactionTypeName, 
    dbo.StockItem.Name, 
    dbo.TransactionType.TransactionGroupID, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN TransactionType.TransactionGroupID = 1 
           THEN transactionhistory.Quantity * - 1 
           ELSE transactionhistory.Quantity 
     END), 
    dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentNo, 
    dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentDate, 
    dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentStatusID
HAVING        
    (dbo.TransactionType.TransactionGroupID <> 0) 
    AND (dbo.TransactionType.TransactionGroupID <> 3) 
    AND (dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentStatusID <> 4)
```

I'm expecting back any results considering the `HAVING` condition. 
However, this query only brings back results where `DocumentStatusID` is present per row, but not all my rows will cross-reference on `dbo.TransactionHistory.Reference = dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.SecondReference`.
`dbo.TransactionHistory.Reference` can exist without `dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.SecondReference`.

I was expecting `LEFT OUTER JOIN` only apply to lines, which have correlation between two tables. It looks like `(dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentStatusID <> 4)` adds compulsory filter by `DocumentStatusID`, which again will not be present on each row. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. A where or having that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: You might want to start using Aliases on your objects. It woul;d make your query a lot more readable/less bloated.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. You don't actually give a spec for your output as a function of input so how can we tell you what a correct query would be? PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. PPS See edit help re how to format your code readably.

Comment: @philipxy I completely forgot I could move `AND dbo.SOPInvoiceCredit.DocumentStatusID <> 4` into `LEFT OUTER JOIN`! And once I done that, I got the correct results! thanks!

Comment: Learn how to use table alias.  The repeating long table names are very annoying.  As you figure by now, no one is going to read that query.